# What is js stands for in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Being am new to stackoverflow. Please help me to get into this community and to clear my doubts.

Thanks,
Bharath

Comment: **J**ava**S**cript

Comment: AngularJS is a javascript framework (JS -> Javascript)  People here will be happy to help but you will probably get heavily downvoted with questions like this that are easily googleable ;) **edit** posted in answer

Comment: js stands for javascript and it is super heroic javascript framework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related.

Comment: off-topic, need ask more specific.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a javascript framework (JS -> Javascript)  People here will be happy to help but you will probably get heavily downvoted with questions like this that are easily googleable ;)

Comment: being am new to this community i 'm not knowing most of semantics.

Comment: When you like an answer, you can upvote it, if you believe it has solved your problem, then you can also tick it as the accepted answer, gives you 2 points of reputation and 15 to the person who answered ;)